# Emitting JSON with yaml-cpp?

Tags: json, yaml, yaml-cpp

I'm using yaml-cpp on a for a variety of things on my project.  Now I want to write out some data as JSON.  Since JSON is a subset of YAML, at least for the features I need, I understand it should be possible to set some options in yaml-cpp to output pure JSON.  How is that done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yaml-cpp doesn't directly have a way to force JSON-compatible output, but you can probably emulate it.

```
YAML:Emitter Emitter;
emitter << YAML:: DoubleQuoted << YAML::Flow << /* rest of code */;
```

Comment: That seems to work for my case, valid JSON is emitted.  I just have one follow on question:
The above results all the JSON being on one long line.  Is there a way to also have it have newlines and indentation?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore, or at least on more complex YAML. I get everything on different rows with YAML style arrays and objects when doing a complex << node output.

Comment: Looks like this might be set on a per node basis? (flow vs no flow)

Comment: this does not work if you have null value. yaml-cpp seems only use ~ as null, I cannot find a way to actually force it use `null`

Answer (score 1):

[Jesse Beder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112/jesse-beder)'s answer didn't seem to work for me; I still got multiple lines of output with YAML syntax. However, I found that by adding `<< YAML::BeginSeq` immediately after `<< YAML::Flow`, you can force everything to end up on one line with JSON syntax. You then have to remove the beginning `[` character:

```cpp
YAML::Emitter emitter;
emitter << YAML::DoubleQuoted << YAML::Flow << YAML::BeginSeq << node;
std::string json(emitter.c_str() + 1);  // Remove beginning [ character
```

[Here is a fully worked example](https://gist.github.com/kerrickstaley/1e1e7c56eede6015b99f4ca47912f7d8).

There's still a major issue, though: numbers are quoted, turning them into strings. I'm not sure whether this is an intentional behavior of `YAML::DoubleQuoted`; looking at the tests, I didn't see any test case that covers what happens when you apply `DoubleQuoted` to a number. This issue has been filed [here](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/941).